# How to add string that starts with '@' into the String.xml file?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-activity

I want to set suffix for the email and want to use string.xml

<string name="emailSuffix">@gmail.com</string>

code is not allowing me to add '@' at start of the string.

Any idea how and what should I do?

I have searched but found nothing but I have tried finding code for '@' like ' , " etc but no result there also.

Comment: What do you mean by "code is not allowing ". What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the error and found solution

just add \ before the @

it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Just Add this "\" before your "@" like below

```
<string name="emailSuffix">\@gmail.com</string>
```

If you have any issues. Let me know